Vue Components Not Rendering After Turbo Form Failure
I'm using @hotwired/turbo, rails 7, vue2 and everything seems to work well except when forms fail and a 422 is returned. The form rerenders with errors, but none of the vue components render. All of this worked prior to replacing turbolinks with turbo.
Interestingly, navigating the site in general seems to load the vue components just fine.
The component that will not render appropriately after form error and turbo reload:
<multiselect>
  ...
  :multiple="true">
</multiselect>

Here is my core javascript setting up my vue app and turbo...
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import Turbo from "@hotwired/turbo-rails"

Rails.start()
ActiveStorage.start()

import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';
    
import TurbolinksAdapter from 'vue-turbolinks'
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm'
// ... other imports

Vue.use(TurbolinksAdapter)

document.addEventListener('turbo:load', () => {

  axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');
  axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
  axios.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json';
    
  Vue.prototype.$csrfToken = document.getElementsByName('csrf-token')[0].content;
  Vue.prototype.$railsDirectUploadsUrl = document.documentElement.dataset.railsDirectUploadsUrl;

  const app = new Vue({
    el: '#vue-app',
    data: function() {
      return {
      }
    },
    methods: {
    },
    components: { 
      Multiselect
      // ... components
    }
  })
})


Any console errors?

@dbugger no there are not. The vue components are in the html structure, just not rendered by vue.

turbo:load only fires on successful responses, when your response is 422 you only get upto turbo:render event.

@Alex makes a lot of sense.. if I instead use turbo:render, it all works as expected. One problem - render doesn't seem to fire on initial load... what would my best practice be here to ensure vue components are rendered properly?

Yes that is an issue with some workarounds, see here: https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/issues/85, https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/issues/520
